# Calculate Cumulative Average using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe as below.

```
Name  2001 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006  
Name1  2    5     0    0    4    6  
Name2  1    4     2    0    4    0  
Name3  0    5     0    0    0    2
```

I wanted to calculate the cumulative average for each row using pandas, But while calculating the Average It has to ignore if the value is zero.

The expected output is as below.

```
Name  2001  2002  2003  2004  2005  2006  
Name1  2    3.5    3.5  3.5   3.75  4.875  
Name2  1    2.5   2.25  2.25  3.125 3.125  
Name3  0     5     5     5    5     3.5
```

Comment: Can you please check your math to make sure we're both on the same page :-)

Comment: Looks like my math was correct, Let's take the first row, At 2005 ((3.5+4)/2) = 3.75, not 3.66

Comment: I see, that's a little different than the cumulative mean I had in mind. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @cs95, Thanks for your help, do you any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Iteratively, since the next value depends on the computed value of the previous iteration. If you are worried about speed you should probably look at numba or cython.

Comment: try using the cumsum function of pandas,it should work fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it seems to me that there is a math problem in your calculations also according to your comments.
If in the first row you are taking 3.5 (that is what you call current cumulative) PLUS 4 (the value at 2005 in the first row) and gives --> (3.5+4)/2= 3.75, then there is an error later in row two column 2005.
In fact, there you have (2.25 + 4)/2 = 3.125.  What you wrote is 3.175.

Now I believe there are a much better ways to implement my solution, but I get what you need here.

```
def cumulative_av(x):
    b=[]
    b.append(x[0])
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        if(x[i]!=0 and b[-1]!=0):
            b.append((x[i]+b[-1])*0.5)
        elif(x[i]!=0 and b[-1]==0):
            b.append(x[i])
        elif(x[i]==0 and b[-1]!=0):
            b.append(b[-1])
        elif(x[i]==0 and b[-1]==0):
            b.append(0)

    return(b)


apd2=pd.DataFrame(columns=["2001", "2002", "2003", "2004", "2005", "2006"])
for i in range(3):
    apd2.loc[i]=cumulative_av(apd.loc[i,].to_list())
```

Where "apd" is your very initial pandas dataframe.   cumulative_av is a function that generates what you have defined (it is a very strange function in my opinion).

Here the results of my code:

```
    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006
0   2.0     3.5     3.50    3.50    3.750   4.875
1   1.0     2.5     2.25    2.25    3.125   3.125
2   0.0     5.0     5.00    5.00    5.000   3.500
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def cumavg(s):
    avg=[s[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(s)):
        if s[i]!=0:
            if avg[i-1] ==0:
                avg.append(s[i])
            else:    
                avg.append((s[i]+avg[i-1])/2)
        else:
            avg.append(avg[-1])
    return np.array(avg)
df.apply(lambda s:cumavg(s),axis='columns')
```

Comment: This counts all numbers and it should exclude de `0`

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your question, I will try on it again and provide an answer

Comment: now it compute the correct output, but  as @Fabrizio mentioned that you have some miscalculations

Answer (score 0):

Given the following dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = {
    '2001': {'Name1': 2, 'Name2': 1, 'Name3': 0},
    '2002': {'Name1': 5, 'Name2': 4, 'Name3': 5},
    '2003': {'Name1': 0, 'Name2': 2, 'Name3': 0},
    '2004': {'Name1': 0, 'Name2': 0, 'Name3': 0},
    '2005': {'Name1': 4, 'Name2': 4, 'Name3': 0},
    '2006': {'Name1': 6, 'Name2': 0, 'Name3': 2}
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

You basically need to perform a `cumsum` (column-wise, so `axis=1`) and then divide it by the `cumsum` of all elements that are not `0`.

This can be done with:

```py
df.cumsum(axis=1) / (df != 0).cumsum(axis=1)
```

The result will be:

```
       2001  2002      2003      2004      2005  2006
Name1   2.0   3.5  3.500000  3.500000  3.666667  4.25
Name2   1.0   2.5  2.333333  2.333333  2.750000  2.75
Name3   NaN   5.0  5.000000  5.000000  5.000000  3.50
```

Comment: As the OP says, there is no 3.66 (neither 2.333 and others).  The "cumulative" function he wants is extremely strange and unfortunately, it's not the solution you put here.